# Princing of simple queries on FireStore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Firestore, I have 1000 documents (e.g. `{ "state": "CA" }, { "state": "NJ" }, ...`, but I want to retrieve a subset of rows (e.g. only `state == CA`).

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
```

If this statement will only return 1 document, **how i will be charged?** Will this transaction cost "1000 reads" or "only 1 read"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Document reads are charged for what is returned. In your scenario you would be charged 1 read, or N reads for how many docs are returned with the state == CA

Comment: But doesn`t count the go through of docs finding where state == CA ?

Comment: No, only the docs returned: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/billing-example#costs-breakdown

Comment: Thanks so much !!